# Событие закрытия вкладки

Tags: javascript

Открываю вкладку и нужно отследить когда она закроется

```
var tab = window.open(url);

tab.onclose = () => {
    console.log('Закрыта вкладка');
}
```

Но так не работает

Answer (score 3):

Советуют использовать [window.onunload, window.onbeforeunload](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded)

**window.onunload**

Когда человек уходит со страницы или закрывает окно, на window срабатывает событие unload. В нём можно сделать что-то, не требующее ожидания, например, закрыть вспомогательные popup-окна, но отменить сам переход нельзя.
Это позволяет другое событие – *onbeforeunload*, которое поэтому используется гораздо чаще.

**window.onbeforeunload**

Если посетитель инициировал переход на другую страницу или нажал «закрыть окно», то обработчик *onbeforeunload* может приостановить процесс и спросить подтверждение.
Для этого ему нужно вернуть строку, которую браузеры покажут посетителю, спрашивая – нужно ли переходить.

Например:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Данные не сохранены. Точно перейти?";
};
```

Также есть ответ на вопрос о действии этих методов [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)

Comment: «строку, которую браузеры покажут посетителю» — многие браузеры её нынче не показывают

Comment: @andreymal Да, это тоже написано в документации по ссылке. Но в вопросе не было ничего сказано о дальнейших действиях. Возможно, автору подойдет и window.onunload.

Comment: Но я так понимаю, этот код нужно писать в той вкладке, которая будет закрыта. А мне нужно получить доступ с другой вкладки

Comment: Для передачи событий между различными окнами браузера можно использовать Ajax-запросы через сервер. Это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: AJAX не лучший способ для передачи данных между вкладками. Возможные варианты перечислены в этой статье — https://blog.arnellebalane.com/sending-data-across-different-browser-tabs-6225daac93ec

Answer (score 1):

```
kva=window.open()
function mjau(){
    if(window.closed) {
        alert('i go go!')
    }
    else {
        alert('Beeeee!')
    }
}
```